# Error occurred while trying to create a project directory

Tags: react-native

I'm re-installing react-native on my mac 2017 intel and I received this message "error Error occurred while trying to create project directory." This is what I originally entered "sudo npx react-native init SprrwNetwrk"

Answer (score 0):

NPM doesn't allow uppercase letters for project directory names, because UNIX filesystems are case sensitive and this might cause confusion.

try it with

```
npx react-native init sprrwnetwrk
```